# How to configuration reverse proxy with auth_request without break api call?

Tags: nginx, authentication

I have a service which can do authorization on `/auth-admin`. I can confirm it works with static web pages. However, if the pages have some api call like login in phpmyadmin, `auth_request` will break it. What it the correct way to set  `auth_request`?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13:8085;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /auth-admin {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13:8085/auth.php?admin;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
        auth_request /auth-admin;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13:8086/;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging around, you need the follow to work with POST request.

```
location /auth-admin {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13:8085/auth.php?admin;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```